# Can an Australian fly from the US to Cuba?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens, cuba

Is it possible to get a direct flight from USA to Cuba if you're not a citizen of either country? I know that to fly out of the US you need to have applied for a Visa which you then pay for and pick up at the airport on your way into Cuba, but is that only for US citizens?

Would an Australian have to organise their travel visa in advance? Would they also need to 'prove to customs' that they were travelling for one of the 12 reasons mandated by OFAC?

I would in particular like to hear anecdotes from people who have travelled to Cuba from the US and were not citizens of the US or Cuba.

Comment: The OFAC rules are enforced by the US government, and they're only enforced when a US citizen or resident returns to the US. If they find that you travelled to Cuba for unauthorized reason (eg. tourism) they'll arrest you for breaking the embargo. Note that this applies to all US residents even those who aren't US citizens.

Comment: @RossRidge I can't remember enough details to find a link now, but in the last month I saw a story (possibly even on here) about a green card holder who travelled to Cuba (I believe without the correct permission) and on entry to the US the authorities initiated revoking his green card.  But a high priced lawyer managed to convince the US authorities otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Australians (and Americans) do **not** need a visa, but they do need a Tourist Card, which can only be applied for with certain Airlines who are authorised to issue them. Otherwise, you need to get it from the Cuban consulate.

Comment: From what I read, this card is basically sold at the gate. Do you know of any airline which flies to Cuba but doesn't?

Comment: @chx Dunno about America, but in Europe Edelweiss and Condor are the only ones I know sell it. Air France, Austrian, Finnair, KLM etc. don't

Comment: @Crazydre could you expand your answer to add that a non-US citizen can board flights from the US to Cuba, but still need submit the OFAC (regardless of the stupid reason). US carriers do have the tourist card available at the departure gate (on the direct leg); I like Alaska Airlines' info as it has the [OFAC](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/cities/flights-to/cuba.aspx) document. Delta lets passengers do it electronically. Right now, it looks like these are current carriers: American, Alaska Airlines/Virgin America, Delta, Southwest, United, JetBlue.