# Australian flying to Havana through Miami

Tags: cuba

I am an Australian passport holder and would like to fly from Miami to Havana. Is this possible? What do I need to prepare?

Comment: You’ll need a tourist visa, which you can usually buy from the airline you’re travelling with, and an OFAC declaration https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120223/ofac-declaration-for-travelling-to-cuba-from-us

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? "Prepare" could cover anything from visas, to vaccinations to what clothes you should bring. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: Are you a US Green Card holder?  Being a legal resident of the US trumps your nationality when it comes to Cuba.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Australian fly from the US to Cuba?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92513/can-an-australian-fly-from-the-us-to-cuba/92515#92515)